# Интересен пример кода,где есть класс отвечающий за пользовательское событие

Tags: java, swing, gui, awt

Т.е  много где видел,что  в Java обычно достаточно быть "слушателем" события,а не его "источником".Интересен именно пример с "источником события".Если есть у кого,буду рад глянуть)

Comment: вы хотите увидеть как генерировать свои события?

Comment: Да,создавать их

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример

```
class MyEvent extends EventObject {
    public MyEvent(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }
}

interface MyEventListener extends EventListener {
    public void myEventOccurred(MyEvent evt);
}

class MyClass {
    protected EventListenerList listenerList = new EventListenerList();

    public void addMyEventListener(MyEventListener listener) {
        listenerList.add(MyEventListener.class, listener);
    }
    public void removeMyEventListener(MyEventListener listener) {
        listenerList.remove(MyEventListener.class, listener);
    }
    void fireMyEvent(MyEvent evt) {
        Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
        for (int i = 0; i < listeners.length; i = i+2) {
            if (listeners[i] == MyEventListener.class) {
                ((MyEventListener) listeners[i+1]).myEventOccurred(evt);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Events {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        c.addMyEventListener(new MyEventListener() {
            public void myEventOccurred(MyEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("fired");
            }
        });

        c.fireMyEvent(new MyEvent(new Object()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю,за пример